# bdaddr is not changing my Bluetooth MAC address

Tags: bluetooth

I have compiled bdaddr on Raspberry Pi 3 B+.

I get

> Address changed - Device reset successfully.

but it does not change the address. Is the Broadcom chip incompatible? If so, what are my options to change my Bluetooth's MAC address?

Comment: You cannot change a device's MAC address; it's burned into the hardware. You can spoof it with software, but that's different entirely. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Well i have done so on my tablet, im pretty sure its possible, maybe not change the hardware, but spoof it as you said. 
I want all my controllers to connect to my "consoles" without having to pair them every time.

Comment: and with the same mac on all devices how do they route to them when more than one is active?

Comment: They are not in the same room. There is enough distance between them, also tablet can just turn off bluetooth, but this is not on topic.

Comment: Can you confirm (as per your comments below) that `bdaddr` does change the address, but it resets after a reboot? If that is the case, you would need to put `bdaddr` in the startup sequence of the RPi.

Comment: I know this, and its not what i said, im writing what bdaddr said, but either i need to find another way to manually reset bluetooth. /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart is not working, it makes my bluetooth disappear so i have to restart the pi to get bluetooth working again. I think that either bdaddr is not compatible with the chip in the raspberrypi 3 or i have not figured out how to properly restart bluetooth.

Answer (score -1):

You should read some manuals, for sure. The MAC is Media Access Control code. It **has to be uinque** "by definition". And I'm sure that pairing 2-3 devices *once* is not a big deal of time and effort.

Comment: I think you do not understand, i play video games on different rooms, and i do not want to and the usb ports are semi inaccessible. I have done this before and know its possible, just have not done it with the raspberrypi. And i do agree that it has to be unique, but not in my purpose. Also only thing i can see going wrong is that the controllers would connect to the wrong bluetooth device. Which they are not because of the distance. And yes i know very well what MAC stands for.......... I think you should read some manuals yourself

Comment: sudo bdaddr -i hci0 -r 00:1B:10:00:2A:EC
Manufacturer:   Broadcom Corporation (15)
Device address: B8:27:EB:14:FE:05
New BD address: 00:1B:10:00:2A:EC

Address changed - Device reset successfully

But it does not actually change, i know i have to do this every reboot.
But thats what init scripts are for.

So is the broadcom chip incompatible with bdaddr?

Comment: @Vatomalo some chips can *temporary* change their parameters, but only a very cheap ones are able to change it permanently - I saw onl yone BT usb stick that could do so, and it was it's only feature, beleive me

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i just need it to do it, dont really need  it to stick permanently since i can create an init script that can change it on boot, but i have now given up on this, and i am going to make a script run sixpair on connecting usb with the right vendor

Comment: @Vatomalo then it's ok - you'll possibly be able to change a BDAddr MAC that way for a session. Be warned - when a bluetooth device will be replugged, i.e. USB renumeration, you must *also* change an address again - so make sure to hook the event up properly